# How to align radio buttons to left of string list in alert dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, alert

I used default Alert dialog with list of string items in it with radio buttons for single select option.

radio buttons are shown to the right of text, I want to display radio buttons to left of strings. Is it possible to show radio buttons to left of strings in Alert dialog ?

Comment: You should search StackOverflow for lots of answers

Comment: can you show xml file that contains radiobuttons

Answer (score 0):

By default the android AlertDialog does not have the RadioButtons on the left. You will have to create your own layout in the adapter that gets use for the AlertDialog.

Comment: I use a cursor to build the dialog, can you let me know how to use custom layout in dialog ? any sample code will be appreciated.